# In Docker WordPress image what causes a delay in copying application files?

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I have created a new `Dockerfile` based on the official WordPress image, and I have been trying to troubleshoot why I cannot remove the default themes. I discovered that the reason is because at the time the command is executed the files do not actually exist yet.

Here are the relevant lines from my Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twenty*
```

The delete command works as expected if I run it manually after the container is running.

As a side note, I have also discovered that when I copy additional custom themes to the `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes` directory, from the `Dockerfile`, it does work but not quite as I would expect. Because any files in the official docker image will overwrite my custom versions of the same file. I would have imagined this to work the other way around, in case I want to supply my own config file.

So I actually have two questions:

1. Is this behavior Docker-related? Or is it in the WordPress-specific image?
2. How can I resolve this? It feels like a hack, but is there a way to asynchronously run a delayed command from the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Please include a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, including the Dockerfile and the commands you use to run your container. If you are using compose, include the yml file. Most importantly, include any volumes you have defined either in the image or as part of running your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's up, Ben!

Your issue is related to a concept introduced by Docker named `entrypoint`. It's typically a script that is executed when the container is run, and contains actions that need to be ran at runtime, not buildtime. That script is ran right after you run the image. They are used to make containers behave like services. The parameters set with the `CMD` directive are, by default, the ones passed directly to the entrypoint, and can be overwritten.

You can find the debian template of the Dockerfile of the image you are pulling [here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/Dockerfile-debian.template). As you can see, it calls an entrypoint named `docker-entrypoint.sh`. Since I don't want to dive into it too much, basically, it's performing the installation of your application.

Since you are inheritating the Wordpress image, the entrypoint of the wordpress image is being executed. Overwriting it so that it is not executed anymore is not a good idea either, since it would render your image useless.

A simple hack that would work in this case would be the following:

```bash
FROM wordpress
RUN sed -i 's/exec \"\$\@\"/exec \"rm -rf \/var\/www\/html\/wp-content\/themes\/twenty\* \&\& \$\@\"/g'
```

That would rewrite the entrypoint, making the last exec clause to remove those files and run whatever service it decided to run (typically apache, but I don't know which could be the case in this container).

I hope that helps! :)